# How to use 3rd party camera app with Ionic React Capacitor

Tags: react-native, capacitor, ionic5

Well the point is the following:

```js
import {
  Camera,
  CameraResultType,
  CameraSource,
  Photo,
} from "@capacitor/camera";

export function usePhotoGallery() { 
  // import { usePhotoGallery } from "../hooks/usePhotoGallery"; per usarlo in esterna

  const scatta = async () => {
    const cameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100,
    });
  };

  return {
    scatta,
  };
}
```

With this pretty basic code just calls the default camera and makes it take a shot.
It's working fine no problem. The issue comes in, by my case, by the fact that i have a custom ROM with no pre-installed camera. So no default camera. I know pretty much no one would have my issue. But I'd like to cover those 0.1% of user that will have this problem.
So, finally, how can I can use a 3rd party camera app? Or just create one if it's better.
For example I can take photos from Whatsapp, Instagram, Snapchat ecc. I guess cuz they have their own camera. So the point basically is:

- How can I make the user select the app he prefers for thake the shot (like the pop-up that ask "open with *choiches*.."
- If i can't do the previous option, then how can I do my own camera?

*Sorry for my probably disgusting english*

Comment: You can use gallery option to select pre clicked photos from your gallery.

Comment: Yeah i know, but I'd like to take photos directly